# How to show vertical movable timeline on Progress bar using angular materials or bootstrap

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-material

Angular screen having mat table with Name and Progress bar. progress will display like 40%, 20% based on some condition. Need to show vertical movable timeline which indicated time on progress bar.
Which angular component can we used for timeline implementation.